# Remove conjugates from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I have this list:

```
 ss = {E^(-3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-3 k x - 3 I t ω), E^(
 3 I k x + 3 I t ω), E^(3 k x + 3 I t ω), 
 E^((-1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^(3 I k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^(-I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-k x - 3 I t ω), E^(
  I k x - 3 I t ω), E^((1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
  E^((2 - I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^(k x - 3 I t ω), 
  E^((2 + I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^(3 k x - 3 I t ω), E^(
  3 I k x - I t ω), E^(3 I k x + I t ω), E^(
  3 k x - I t ω), E^(3 k x + I t ω), 
  E^(-3 I k x - I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - I t ω), 
  E^(-3 I k x + I t ω), E^((1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), 
  E^((1 - 2 I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^(-3 I k x + 3 I t ω), 
  E^(-3 k x - I t ω), E^(-I k x - I t ω), 
  E^(-k x - I t ω), E^(I k x - I t ω), E^(
  k x - I t ω), E^(I k x + I t ω), E^(
   k x + I t ω), E^(I k x + 3 I t ω), E^(
   k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), 
   E^(-I k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-1 - 2 I) k x + 3 I t ω), 
   E^(-I k x + I t ω), E^(-3 k x + I t ω), 
   E^((-2 + I) k x + I t ω), E^(-k x + I t ω), 
   E^((-2 + I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^(-k x + 3 I t ω), 
    E^((-2 - I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^(-3 k x + 3 I t ω)};
```

This list has 44 elements. In fact, it has 22 pairs of functions and their conjugates, for example E^(-3 I k x - 3 I t ω) and E^(3 I k x + 3 I t ω). What I need is just to select the functions without the conjugates, so my list is shrunk to a size of 22. I have so many similar lists and want this to be automatic.

Comment: The code that I gave does not remove actual duplicates with non zero imaginary parts, for example `DeleteDuplicates[{1 + I, 1 + I}, #1 == ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[x1_, x2_] -> Complex[x1, -x2]] &]` has the output `{1 + I, 1 + I}`. This is in principle what was asked (you asked to remove conjugates not all duplicates)  but it might be unexpected. You could include another DeleteDuplicates to remove all duplicates or use the code by @user293787.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

#### Motivation and explanation (code section below)

( This section can be skipped )

The desired output can be achieved with `ComplexExpand` but that function can be a bit heavy as it transforms `Exp` into `Cos` and `Sin` which is unnecessary for this task. Moreover, `Conjugate` assumes every variable is potentially complex so it does not help without including assumptions on the variables. Another option is to make an easy home-cooked conjugation for the problem at hand. Let's see how.

```
E^((1 - 2 I) k x + 3 I t \[Omega]) // FullForm
```

out:  `(* Power[E,Plus[Times[Complex[1,-2],k,x],Times[Complex[0,3],t,\[Omega]]]] *)`

Manually changing all the `I`'s to -`I` we have:

```
E^((1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t \[Omega]) // FullForm
```

out:  `(* Power[E,Plus[Times[Complex[1,2],k,x],Times[Complex[0,-3],t,\[Omega]]]] *)`

The change is that `Complex[1,-2]` became `Complex[1,2]` and `Complex[0,3]` became `Complex[0,-3]`, this is the  home-cooked conjugation that we will use.

---

#### The code :

```
ssr = DeleteDuplicates[ss,
      #1 == ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[r1_, r2_] -> Complex[r1, -r2]] &]
```

**Note:** this code does not remove actual duplicates with non zero imaginary parts for example `DeleteDuplicates[{1 + I, 1 + I}, #1 ==  ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[x1_, x2_] -> Complex[x1, -x2]] &]` has the output `{1 + I, 1 + I}`. This is in principle what was asked  but it might be unexpected.

We can check that `ssr` has the same output as the method using `ComplexExpand` in the answer provided by @MarcoB:

```
ssr == DeleteDuplicates[ss,
       ComplexExpand@Conjugate@#1 == ComplexExpand@#2 &]
```

out: `(* True *)`

The timing is different (I used `AbsoluteTiming`):

**Using ComplexExpand :**  0.44 s

**Custom conjugate with ReplaceAll :**  0.0054 s

---

**Note:** Not every function has a conjugate in the list given. This can be checked with the code below:

```
Complement[ss, ReplaceAll[ss, Complex[r1_, r2_] -> Complex[r1, -r2]]]
```

`(` **Explanation of the code above if needed** (an example might be easier to understand than what I wrote): there are two types of elements in the list ss, those that have a conjugate and those that don't. For those that do, the action of conjugation swaps the elements with their conjugates but no new elements are created. For the elements that do not have a conjugate, conjugations creates new elements. Complement above asks for the elements in the original ss that do not exist in the conjugated list. Such elements in the original ss can not have a conjugate as conjugation would swap but not create new distinct elements. Hence they are the ones with no conjugate. `)`

There are 8 terms that do not have a conjugate. Hence, as the original list has 44 elements, the list that we obtain after removing conjugates has (44-8)/2+8=26 elements.

---

#### Time complexity of DeleteDuplicates and DeleteDuplicatesBy

I was unaware that `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is a lot faster than `DeleteDuplicates` when a test function is included. @user293787 pointed this out in the comments under the answer given there. I was authorized to include this information in my answer (although any mistakes below are my own).

Specifically, @user293787 pointed out that when a generic test function is used, when the number of duplicates scales with the size of the list and seemingly (at least from my personal tests although this is still unclear to me) when the number of possible pairwise comparisons also scales with the size of the list (unlike duplicates modulo 2 for example), then `DeleteDuplicates` does a naive comparison of all possible pairs which, if the length of the list is $n$, that number of comparisons scales like $n^2$. `DeleteDuplicatesBy` essentially Maps a function to each list and then applies the usual algorithm for DeleteDuplicates when no test function is specified. As @user293787 pointed out, when no test function is used, DeleteDuplicates can use Sort (maybe Ordering is easier to reproduce DeleteDuplicates, not sure). Fast sorting algorithms have a time complexity of $n\log(n)$ on average and $n$ in the best case, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) page or this [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) page.

To show this I will compare the method proposed by @user293787 in the comments with the method above that uses DeleteDuplicates . I will use a similar test list as the one used by OP.

**Note!:** The code by @user293787 deletes both conjugates and duplicates. This might or might not be desired. To compare the two methods I also included an extra DeleteDuplicates in the method above as it does **not** delete duplicates with a non zero imaginary part (OP did not request that all duplicates should be removed just the conjugates)

```
Table[ss = 
  Exp[a*RandomChoice[Range[-2, 2], i] + 
    I*b*RandomChoice[Range[-2, 2], i]];
 
 s1 = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   DeleteDuplicates@
    DeleteDuplicates[
     ss, #1 == 
       ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[x1_, x2_] -> Complex[x1, -x2]] &]];
 
 s2 = AbsoluteTiming[DeleteDuplicatesBy[ss, ccpair]];
 
 If[s1[[2]] != s2[[2]], Abort[]];
 
 {{i, s1[[1]]}, {i, s2[[1]]}}, {i, 10, 1000, 100}] // 
OperatorApplied[Table][10] // Mean // Transpose // 
ListPlot[#, 
PlotLegends -> {"DeleteDuplicates", "DeleteDuplicatesBy"}, 
AxesLabel -> {"list length", "time (s)"}] &
```

output:

[image: comparison]

To conclude, for small list lengths, the choice depends on the preferred syntax. For larger list lengths where no duplicates are desired, it might be better to use the DeleteDuplicatesBy method given in the comments by @user293787 (after writing that number sequence so much I ended up remembering it so well that I could almost forget my own passwords)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't know why your last command for checking the existence of conjugates fails to show that E^((2 - I) k x - I t \[Omega]), E^((-2 + I) k x + I t \[Omega]) are conjugates.

Comment: @qahtah Hi, the last command does not fail as the two quantities you mentioned are not conjugates. k x is real, changing 2 k x to -2 k x is not a conjugation.

Comment: @qahtah see user293787's answer for an even faster way. That said, sometimes readability (for others reading your code and for yourself in the future when you have to read it again) should be considered more than  speed if the code is fast enough that computer time is not much of an issue.

Comment: @qahtah also to be on the safe side, including ExpandAll on both sides of the equality could be good. That said, if the the list was generated algorithmically, a priori, an element and its conjugate would be factorized the same way. To see why compare: `DeleteDuplicates[{2*r + 2*I, 2 (I + r)}]` with `DeleteDuplicates[{2*r + 2*I, 2 (I + r)}, 
 ExpandAll[#1] == ExpandAll[#2] &]`

Comment: I believe that I lost a point so I guess someone down voted the answer. Does anyone have an idea why that could happen ? I do not understand the idea of down voting without commenting if there is no clear/obvious reason why.

Comment: If you click on "Show activity on this post" and then "Show vote summaries", it lists a total of 4 up (one of which from me) and 0 down. This probably does not exclude that somebody gave you an upvote and then removed it again, I do not know. I would not worry about it.

Comment: @user293787 thank you I did not know I could check for down votes like that. Yes, maybe someone removed a vote in which case it might be related to the idea that the code does not work due to the comment where supposedly the two elements mentioned were conjugates. If that's the case it's fine if it's not something inherently bad about the answer.  Also my memory could just be faulty. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 7):

```
DeleteDuplicates[ss, ComplexExpand@ Conjugate@ #1 == ComplexExpand@ #2 &]

(* Out, 26 elements:
{E^(-3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-3 k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^(3 k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω),
 E^(3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-I k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^(-k x - 3 I t ω), E^(I k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^((1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^(k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 + I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
 E^(3 I k x - I t ω), E^(3 I k x + I t ω), 
 E^(3 k x - I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - I t ω), 
 E^((1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^(-3 k x - I t ω),
 E^(-I k x - I t ω), E^(-k x - I t ω),
 E^(I k x - I t ω), E^(k x - I t ω),
 E^((-1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^((-2 + I) k x + I t ω),
 E^((-2 + I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-2 - I) k x + 3 I t ω)}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

This function generates a pair of a complex number and its complex conjugate:

```
ccpair[z_]:=Sort[ExpandAll[ComplexExpand[{z,Conjugate[z]}]]];

(* example *)
ccpair[x+I*y]

(* {x-I y,x+I y} *)
```

One can then use

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[ss,ccpair]

(* {E^(-3 I k x-3 I t ω),E^(-3 k x-3 I t ω),E^(3 k x+3 I t ω),
    E^((-1+2 I) k x-3 I t ω),E^(3 I k x-3 I t ω),E^(-I k x-3 I t ω),
    E^(-k x-3 I t ω),E^(I k x-3 I t ω),E^((1+2 I) k x-3 I t ω),
    E^((2-I) k x-3 I t ω),E^(k x-3 I t ω),E^((2+I) k x-3 I t ω),
    E^(3 I k x-I t ω),E^(3 I k x+I t ω),E^(3 k x-I t ω),
    E^((2-I) k x-I t ω),E^((1-2 I) k x+I t ω),E^(-3 k x-I t ω),
    E^(-I k x-I t ω),E^(-k x-I t ω),E^(I k x-I t ω),E^(k x-I t ω),
    E^((-1-2 I) k x+I t ω),E^((-2+I) k x+I t ω),E^((-2+I) k x+3 I t ω),
    E^((-2-I) k x+3 I t ω)} *)
```

**Notes.**

- Since `ccpair` is only applied once to each entry, this will scale pretty well to larger lists, with essentially linear time complexity.
- The `ExpandAll` above is intended to put the expressions into some sort of normal form. If expressions are always `Exp` of some polynomial, then I would probably first take the `Log`, apply the `DeleteDuplicatesBy` operation to polynomials, then apply `Exp` again:

```
  Exp[DeleteDuplicatesBy[ss/.E^p_:>p,ccpair]]
  (* same result as above but faster *)
```

Comment: Using the idea in the answer by @userrandrand, an alternative definition of `ccpair` would be `ccpair[z_]:=Sort[ExpandAll[{z,z/.Complex[u_,v_]:>Complex[u,-v]}]]`. If OP has very **long** lists (say several hundred entries) and speed is a concern, then I think the fastest solution so far is this answer here using `DeleteDuplicatesBy` (not `DeleteDuplicates`) together with the new version of `ccpair` in this comment.

Comment: Nice. The first time I saw your answer I did not take the time to understand the idea for ccpair and why there was a Sort there. By a simplicity bias (in other words, by my personal laziness) I assumed MarcoB's more straightforward answer was inherently the better choice. Do you know why DeleteDuplicatesBy is faster ?

Comment: If `list` has length $n$ and one uses `DeleteDuplicates[list,test]` then I expect `test` will be invoked $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ many times, if it compares each element with each, which is the best it can do if no axiomatic assumptions are made about `test`. (Fewer are needed for `SameQ` because one can sort. This explains why `DeleteDuplicates[list,SameQ]` is much faster than `DeleteDuplicates[list,SameQ[##]&]`.) If one uses `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list,f]` then `f` will only be invoked $\mathcal{O}(n)$ many times, after that it will essentially run a `DeleteDuplicates[...,SameQ]` which is fast.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I did not consider that DeleteDuplicates might use nlog[n] sorting algorithms whereas DeleteDuplicates[list,test] might do a naive n^2 computation testing all pairs. I compared `SameQ` with `SameQ[##]&` on the test list below. I did not see n^2 scaling for `SameQ[##]&` but it was clearly slower. The code I used: `test = SameQ[##] &;
Mean[Table[
   Table[AbsoluteTiming[
      DeleteDuplicates[RandomChoice[Range[4], i], test]] // First, {i,
      1, 10^4, 10^2}], 10]] // ListPlot`

Comment: Thanks. One can use `count[max_,n_] := Module[{c=0}, DeleteDuplicates[ RandomChoice[Range[max],n], (c++;SameQ[##])&]; N[c/n^2]]` to count how often it calls the test function. You used `max=4` (lists with at most 4 distinct elements) in which case it does not scale quadratically in $n$, probably because it first makes a list of distinct elements. But if `max` is similar to $n$, then there are about $n^2$ calls.

Comment: Thank you for the neat count function. I found $n^2$ scaling now after replacing `RandomChoice[Range[4], i]` by `RandomChoice[Range[Floor[i/2]], i]` and `{i, 1, 10^4, 10^2}` to `{i, 1, 10^4, 10^2}` with `SameQ[##]&` using both `AbsoluteTiming` and your count function. However, using `test=Mod[#1, 2] == Mod[#2, 2] &` the scaling was still linear in both cases . In your code I replaced `(c++;SameQ[##])&` with `(c++; Mod[#1, 2] == Mod[#2, 2]) &`. Maybe checking equality Modulo two is equivalent to using `RandomChoice[Range[2],n]` in terms of complexity.

Comment: Last test, I used the test list : `RandomChoice[Range[Floor[i/2]], i] + 
 I*RandomChoice[Range[Floor[i/2]], i]` in the code above and the test function #1 == ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[b1_, b2_] -> Complex[b1, -b2]] & and I saw $n^2$ scaling. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe a graph with the complexity scaling  extending OP's list could be interesting to compare the two methods. I am interested in making it (I would cite this discussion) but it's your knowledge so maybe it is better on your answer, not sure.

Comment: Feel free to include in your post whatever you find interesting and relevant.

Comment: Actually it's good that I did the benchmarking as I learned the code I gave does not remove actual duplicates that have an imaginary part while your method does. For example DeleteDuplicates[{1 + I, 1 + I}, #1 == ReplaceAll[#2, Complex[x1_, x2_] -> Complex[x1, -x2]] &] outputs the same list. The request OP gave did not ask to remove duplicates just to remove conjugates so maybe it does more than the strict necessary. However, perhaps OP also expected duplicates to be removed. Not sure. I will mention this in my answer.

Comment: @userrandrand Using `GatherBy[ss, ComplexExpand[Re[#]] &][[All, 1]]` in your computer, what is the timing?

Comment: @E.Chan-López around 0.02 seconds. `DeleteDuplicatesBy[ss, ComplexExpand[Re[#]] &]` has a similar timing

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for answering my question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
Normal[GroupBy[ss, ComplexExpand[#*ComplexExpand[Conjugate[#]]] &]][[All, 2]][[All, 1]]
```

[image]

Using `GatherBy`:

```
GatherBy[ss, ComplexExpand[#*ComplexExpand[Conjugate[#]]] &][[All, 1]]
```

[image]

Sorting with the real part and using `GatherBy` is much faster than the previous sort:

```
GatherBy[ss, ComplexExpand[Re[#]] &][[All, 1]]
(*{0.060014, {E^(-3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-3 k x - 3 I t ω),
E^(3 k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
E^(3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-I k x - 3 I t ω), 
E^(-k x - 3 I t ω), E^(I k x - 3 I t ω), 
E^((1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
E^(k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 + I) k x - 3 I t ω), 
E^(3 I k x - I t ω), E^(3 I k x + I t ω), 
E^(3 k x - I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - I t ω), 
E^((1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^(-3 k x - I t ω), 
E^(-I k x - I t ω), E^(-k x - I t ω), 
E^(I k x - I t ω), E^(k x - I t ω), 
E^((-1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^((-2 + I) k x + I t ω),
E^((-2 + I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-2 - I) k x + 3 I t ω)}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

A hash-free variant of E. Chan-López answer

```
GatherBy[Re /@ ss, ComplexExpand][[All, 1, 1]]
```

> {E^(-3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-3 k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^(3 k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^(3 I k x - 3 I t ω), E^(-I k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^(-k x - 3 I t ω), E^(I k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^((1 + 2 I) k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^(k x - 3 I t ω), E^((2 + I) k x - 3 I t ω),
> E^(3 I k x - I t ω), E^(3 I k x + I t ω),
> E^(3 k x - I t ω), E^((2 - I) k x - I t ω),
> E^((1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^(-3 k x - I t ω),
> E^(-I k x - I t ω), E^(-k x - I t ω),
> E^(I k x - I t ω), E^(k x - I t ω),
> E^((-1 - 2 I) k x + I t ω), E^((-2 + I) k x + I t ω),
> E^((-2 + I) k x + 3 I t ω), E^((-2 - I) k x + 3 I t ω)}}